# add a bunch of rows from csv, then keep counting primary key where that left off (postgres, flask-sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, primary-key, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a postgres database that I'm mainly interacting with in python using sqlalchemy (via flask-sqlalchemy).  I'd like to be able to add the initial data for my tables directly in psql from a CSV, and then be able to programmatically add new rows later.

But I'm having problems with my primary key.  Specifically, if I include it in the csv file for the initial data, then when I try to add new rows programmatically, the new rows try to start the primary key at 1, and promptly fail because that key already exists.

**Details and code**

The relevant part of my sqlalchemy code:

```
class Contracts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "contracts"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    contract = db.Column(db.Text())
    # a bunch of other columns that are irrelevant follow here

    def __init__(self, contract, url, firstadded, firstaddedby):
        self.contract = contract
        # and all the other irrelevant columns.  
        # not ID, because that's to be auto-incremented.
```

I then create the tables from the python shell with:

```
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

Confirming that this produced what I expected, the relevant parts of the first two rows of `\d+ contracts` in psql:

```
id      | integer        | not null default nextval('contracts_id_seq'::regclass)
contract| text           |
```

So then, I have a csv file as follows:

```
1,this is a word,http://foo.bar,never,test,f,,,,,
2,this is a word or t20,http://foo.baz,never,test,f,,,,,
```

which I add to the contracts table from psql as follows: 
`\copy contracts from 'path/to/csv/file' with (format csv);`

and, as expected, selecting from the table reveals two rows, with ids 1 and 2.

But then suppose I open up a shell and try to enter some data with the sqlalchemy code:

```
>>>from database import Contracts
>>> k = Contracts("here's some text", "url column", "firstadded column", "firstaddedby column")
>>> db.session.add(k)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

but it fails with the expected error (in relevant part) `(psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "contracts_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.`

I tried to just remove the first column from the csv, or leave it blank, on the theory that maybe posgres could be convinced to start an auto-incrementing index if it wasn't supplied.  But in both cases importing the csv failed--- removing failed because it treated the second column as the id and blew up with an `invalid input syntax for integer` --- adding an empty column failed because it violated the not-null constraint.

Help?  Surely there's a straightforward way to add rows from a csv and then continue counting up the primary key where that left off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [setval the sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) after your import:

```
select setval('contracts_id_seq', max(id)) from contracts;
```